# ZeroMQ publisher not binding after forever restartall

Tags: node.js, sockets, zeromq, forever

**Scenario**

I am have multiple NodeJS scripts running in forever mode in Ubuntu OS. One of these files(*start.js*) imports a file that starts a ZMQ publisher by biding it to a specified port. When I start this *start.js* file in forever mode separately, it binds and starts the publisher, and I am able to fetch the data published by this publisher through a ZMQ subscriber that connects to this port.

I am closing the publisher gracefully by checking for exit, SIGINT and SIGUSR events.

Whenever I restart this **start.js** file alone using `forever restart`, the publisher binds and starts successfully. It also works fine if I stop it manually (using `forever stop`) and start it again using `forever start` [ also works in the case where I manually stop(using `forever stopall`) and start all the forever scripts one by one].

***NOTE: All the forever stop and restart commands are run with CLI option --killSignal=SIGINT.***

**Problem**

But the publisher is failing to bind when I do `forever restartall --killSignal=SIGINT`. It says that the address is already in use(I have checked this using `netstat` and there is no tcp socket at that port). When I stop all the scripts and start them one by one it binds back normally and starts successfully.

I have checked that these kill signals are caught by the publisher script and its closing the publisher socket before exiting.

**Failed Attempts:**

- Lowered the TIME_WAIT state of the tcp sockets.
- Enabled reuse of TIME_WAIT sockets.
- I thought that the tcp socket is taking time to get released from
  TIME_WAIT state, and tried to bind the publisher after 1000ms on
  every failure to bind, but the scripts is trying to bind and failing
  every time it tries.
- Tried forever restarting all the scripts using SIGINT, SIGUSR1 kill
  signals and handled them in the script that binds the publisher
  socket.

This is how I am handling the SIG* events in the publisher:

```
process.stdin.resume();
function exitHandler(options, err){
    if (options.cleanup) console.log('pub-clean');
    if (err) console.log("pub--" + err.stack);
    if (options.exit){
        socket.close();
        console.log("Publisher Closed")
        process.exit();
    }
}

process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true}));
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null,{exit:true}));
process.on('SIGUSR2', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));
process.on('SIGTERM', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));
```

**Why the forever restarting all the scripts is causing the publisher script to fail to bind?**

**What can be done to make the publisher script to bind on forever restarting?**

Comment: How have you implemented the **`SIG*`**-s handlers in your code to gracefully clost/terminate/exit all the ZeroMQ resouces & Context(s)?

Comment: @user3666197 >> I have included the code-snippet for handling SIG* events above.

Comment: Well, as seen, your **`SIG*`**-handlers' code does nothing in a direction to gracefully close/terminate the ZeroMQ resources. Would you kindly post your code with a setup-part of the ZeroMQ initialisation?

Comment: @user3666197 > why the SIG* handlers' code does nothing? Without this code when ever the process receives a SIGINT or SIGTERM or exit signal it will not close the socket.

Comment: With due respect, **gracefull release of ZeroMQ resources** is **not** done via system-level SIG* / *KILL, but by executing the ZeroMQ-gracefull-release steps. As posted so far, you do not do that at all in your code and thus the ZeroMQ-resources may and most probably remain hanging ( at least the I/O-thread seems to ).

Answer (score 0):

### ZeroMQ-resources are recommended to be released in a controlled way

As discussed in the comments above, a **truly graceful** release of ZeroMQ resources is **not** done via system-level **`SIG*`** / **`*KILL`**, but by executing the ZeroMQ-recommended graceful-release steps.

As posted so far, you do not do that at all in your code and thus the ZeroMQ-resources may and most probably remain hanging ( at least the I/O-thread seems to ).

Check your ZeroMQ-socket settings used in ( not yet posted ) setup ( **`.setsockopt()`** calls used in setup phase ) and add:

1. ensure settings for a non-blocking **`.close()`** of all sockets setup ( be they used, or not )
2. then execute **`.close()`** only after [**1**] is sure and valid
3. finally, execute explicit ZeroMQ **`Context`** instance **`.term()`**

This is considered a guaranteed ZeroMQ-graceful-release of all ( internally handled ) resources.

---

---

### On a sample code request:

A graceful release

```
void  msLIB.deinit() {
      aComment.ADD( "msLIB.INFO: msLIB.deinit() TracePOINT.<BoPROC>|", False );

   // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<THANKS>
   // DO NOT EDIT: the below  IS TRULY NEEDED or else one might get some nice memory leaks!
   // ------------            |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||   


   // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   // ZMQ-IMPERATIVE ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
   // _______________________________________________________________________ msMOD: ZMQ_Safe&CleanCODE_IMPERATIVE
      zmq_setsockopt(   zmqSpeaker,  ZMQ_LINGER, 0 );                         // no Sending QUEUE .... on ZMQ_PUBLISHER end
      zmq_close(        zmqSpeaker  );                                        // Protect against memory leaks on shutdown.
                        aComment.ADD( "<1>", False );
                        aComment.ADD( " [[[ZMQ]]]<speaker_socket>.set( ZMQ_LINGER ) / .close()-ed ", True );

      zmq_setsockopt(   zmqListener, ZMQ_LINGER, 0 );                         // aKBD.PUB 
      zmq_close(        zmqListener );                                        // Protect against memory leaks on shutdown.
                        aComment.ADD( "<2>", False );
                        aComment.ADD( " [[[ZMQ]]]<listener_socket>.set( ZMQ_LINGER ) / .close()-ed ", True );      

      zmq_term(         zmqContext  );                                        // Protect against memory leaks on shutdown.
                        aComment.ADD( "<3>", False );
                        aComment.ADD( " [[[ZMQ]]]<context>.term()-ed ", True );

   // _______________________________________________________________________ msMOD: ZMQ_Safe&CleanCODE_IMPERATIVE

   // ------------
   // DO NOT EDIT: the above  IS TRULY NEEDED or else one might get some nice memory leaks!               
   // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<THANKS>

      aComment.ADD( "|<EoPROC>", False );
      msLIB.aSnapshot.MAKE();
      aComment.ADD( "|aSnapshot.MAKE()-<DONE>", True );
      return;
   }
```

---

---

### On missing "in-built" controls

One may extend the architecture so as to contain one's own soft-signalling code for all the situations, that need to get handled softer, than via **`SIGKILL`** et al.

[image: a simpler case]

and

[image: a more complex case]

Comment: @user36666197 >> Thanks for reply :), could you provide some sample code on how to do this in NodeJS? I could only find a section on handling interrupt signals for CTRL-C in ZMQ guide [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Handling-Interrupt-Signals)

Comment: @saikiranboga check the update. Designing a code as a principally non-blocking ( which is one of the ZeroMQ biggest maxims ) simplifies the need for system-level signalling and dependencies on their ( where available ) handlers + allows you to build all the code around a layer of non-blocking soft-signalling between ( again non-blocking ) processes.

Comment: @user36666197 >> I was able to setup setsockopt with linger option as 0 and also close the socket, but I see no option for closing the zmq context in NodeJS. I have checked the module code [here](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/lib/index.js), they are setting context to null, rather than closing it, donno whether this might be causing the problem.